# Recommend Deletion option in Late Answers review queue does nothing - please flag posts that should be deleted

Tags: support, review, flagging, late-answers

Just a quick PSA here - thanks to [BeastOfCaerbannog](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/618353/beastofcaerbannog) I've realised that the new *Recommend Deletion* option in the Late Answers queue completes the review and gives you the option to leave the canned comments from the Low Quality Posts queue, but otherwise **does absolutely nothing**.

If you encounter a post in Late Answers that should be deleted, please flag it. You can then go ahead and use the Recommend Deletion option (although I feel it's completely misleading and [should be removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371918/remove-or-rename-the-ineffective-recommend-deletion-option-from-late-answers) - [or open a flagging dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371947/322419)), but be aware that it does nothing towards deleting the post, whereas flagging the post sends it to the Low Quality Posts queue and also brings it to the attention of mods.

Thanks a lot!

P.S. I also recommend flagging posts that should be deleted in the Low Quality Posts queue, especially if they are spam or abusive. While some posts there already have flags, many are put into the queue automatically and don't have flags. Flagging may speed up handling of the posts by bringing them to the attention of mods. This will clear the queue faster.

Comment: IIRC 6 "Recommends Deletion"s would result in a post getting deleted. Did that change?

Comment: @muru that happens in the Low Quality Posts queue. This is a new option in the Late Answers queue. It doesn't do anything

Comment: Oh, I see it now.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a [meta-tag:bug]? Sounds like the system isn't doing what it is supposed to.

Comment: @terdon it’s already raised on meta, raising another bug report on a per-site meta likely wouldn’t help. Also, this is a PSA, so [tag:support] makes sense.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica Can I have a link to the existing report on Meta please?

Comment: @cocomac it's linked in the post ^ but: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371918/remove-or-rename-the-ineffective-recommend-deletion-option-from-late-answers - actually I don't think this is unintended, it's just a misfeature

Comment: @Zanna Thanks for linking it! I'll probobly toss a bounty on it tomorrow or Friday. I've been using the Late Answers, thinking it failed. Personally, I'd like to be able to leave a comment _and_ flag it as needed

Comment: @cocomac thanks! yes I think if the option exists at all it should bring up a flagging dialog. I do see value in having the low quality posts queue comments available as well

Comment: @Zanna Yup. As I mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371918/remove-or-rename-the-ineffective-recommend-deletion-option-from-late-answers#comment1242485_371918), I'd appreciate if it let me use a canned comment, followed immediately by the flag dialog. As someone less than 10k, I thought suggesting deletion (a) left the comment, but (b) also put it into some sort of queue for high rep users/mods to deal with. I'm honestly very surprised that it doesn't